# How to display the datagridview rowheaders on the right?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview which displays row numbers in the rowheaders on the left.   One of the users has asked for them to be on the right instead.  The display of row numbers is fine, it's the location of the rowheaders that's the issue here.

I have looked through various properties and can't find anything that switches the row header over to the other side.
I realise I could add another column to the right and format it to look like the rowheaders, but that seems like a clumsy workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting the `RightToLeft` property of the datagridview?

```
Me.DataGridView1.RightToLeft = Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes
```

Bear in mind that this reverses the display order of the columns, which you would have to manage as well, if you want to give the appearance that the only thing to change is the position of the rowheader.

Comment: Such a simple solution. Thank you!